# Is it possible to return map response from Functional interface in java

Tags: java, java-8

In the below code,I would like to return map from Functional interface.
But I am getting error from the below code. Thanks in Advance.

```
Function< Employee, Map< String, Integer > > funcEmpToString = ( Employee e ) -> {
    Map map = new HashMap< String, Integer >( );
    map.put( e.getName( ), e.getNumber( ) )
    return map;
};

import java.util.*;

public class FunctionExample {

    public static List< String > convertEmpListToNamesList( List< Employee > employeeList, Function< Employee, String > funcEmpToString ) {

        List< String > empNameList = new ArrayList< String >( );
        for ( Employee emp : employeeList ) {
            empNameList.add( funcEmpToString.apply( emp ) );
        }
        return empNameList;
    }

    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        Function< Employee, String > funcEmpToString = ( Employee e ) -> {return e.getName( );};

        List< Employee > employeeList = Arrays.asList( new Employee( "Tom Jones", 45 ),
                new Employee( "Harry Major", 25 ),
                new Employee( "Ethan Hardy", 65 ),
                new Employee( "Nancy Smith", 15 ),
                new Employee( "Deborah Sprightly", 29 ) );

        List< String > empNameList = convertEmpListToNamesList( employeeList, funcEmpToString );
        empNameList.forEach( System.out::println );
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Yes, it is possible (why not?)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: The above code, even formatted correctly wouldnt even compile (with the imports in the middle of something, Please carefully format your code to make sense.

Comment: You can't assign a map to a string.

Comment: Hi guys, I am unable to ask questions, I think it's due to asking getting -3 for this question. I will follow the rules carefully now on wards. Could you please me the remedy to restore my account status.@GhostCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Yes it is possible.
2- I would need further information to assist you, as you did not told us about the error, I am assuming you are having issues with you missing semicolon:

```
map.put(e.getName(), e.getNumber())
```

Here is your code rewritten as example in a single snippet:

```
package other;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionExample {
    private static class Employee{
        private String name;
        private int number;
        Employee(String name, int number){
            this.name=name;
            this.number = number;
        }

        private int getNumber( ) {

            return number;
        }

        private String getName( ) {

            return name;
        }
    }

    Function< Employee, Map< String, Integer > > funcEmpToString = ( Employee e ) -> {
        Map map = new HashMap< String, Integer >( );
        map.put( e.getName( ), e.getNumber( ) );
        return map;
    };

    public static List< String > convertEmpListToNamesList( List< Employee > employeeList, Function< Employee, String > funcEmpToString ) {

        List< String > empNameList = new ArrayList< String >( );
        for ( Employee emp : employeeList ) {
            empNameList.add( funcEmpToString.apply( emp ) );
        }
        return empNameList;
    }

    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        Function< Employee, String > funcEmpToString = ( Employee e ) -> { return e.getName( );};

        List< Employee > employeeList = Arrays.asList( new Employee( "Tom Jones", 45 ),
                new Employee( "Harry Major", 25 ),
                new Employee( "Ethan Hardy", 65 ),
                new Employee( "Nancy Smith", 15 ),
                new Employee( "Deborah Sprightly", 29 ) );

        List< String > empNameList = convertEmpListToNamesList( employeeList, funcEmpToString );
        empNameList.forEach( System.out::println );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean missing semicolon, `;`?

Comment: yes sir I did. will fiz ;)